# Is there a way to highlight all the text in matching braces or tags in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

So in IntelliJ if you have something like this:

```
if (!loggedIn) {
    resp.sendRedirect("loginServlet");
    return;
}
```

when you put the cursor next to first { the matching } will be highlighted. What I want is that all the text between these braces are highlighted. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the feature you are looking for is [Expand Selection](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#d1272266e277).

> **To extend selection from the word at the caret to the piece of code
>   the caret is contained in, use the following shortcuts**
>
> - Press Ctrl+W to select the word where the caret is currently located.
> - Press Ctrl+W successively to extend selection to the next containing node (for example, an expression, a paired tag, an entire
>     conditional block, a method body, a class, a group of vararg
>     arguments, etc.)

Put your cursor anywhere inside "the matching", and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (by default on Windows) successively.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hi @Huangism, thanks for your feedback! Can you point what exactly I could do to improve this answer?

Comment: Like the boiler template message says, copy the essential part of the answer from the link to your answer, so that if the link is dead, the answer can still be used

Comment: Got it. Updated the answer with the essential part. Unfortunately I was already downvoted for some unknow reason :)

Comment: Wasn't me but probably because it was a link only answer or the user thought your solution is incorrect

Comment: I will upload it but I am looking for something that will automatically do this everytime I am in a code block.

Comment: You won't find anything that does this "automatically" because the IDE can't make this asumption. Technically it could, but I'm really sure that the majority of developers wouldn't like having their entire block of code highlighted everytime they go near a braces.

Comment: Agreed, it's unlikely that anyone wants to highlight the code automatically. Expand Selection is the best thing you can get, just one hotkey to get the job done. If it's not enough, your only option is to write a plugin that will highlight the block when the caret is placed after the opening brace. It should not be too hard if you really can't live without it.